# JSON error on checkout with WooCommerce Payments

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

A WooCommerce site I manage has recently started having issues with credit/debit card payments through WooCommerce Payments.

Every single payment fails with the following message:

[image: Error stating: We're not able to process this payment. Please refresh the page and try again.]

In the Inspector, I get this error.

[image: Web Inspector showing JSON error with code 'woocommerce_rest_checkout_process_payment_error']

We're running a basic Block theme with some custom custom blocks, but all the WooCommerce checkout stuff should be completely vanilla.

We haven't made any code changes close to when this issue started happening, although updates could have happened in the background. I don't have exact dates for when the issue started occurring, but it looks to have been around the time WP 6.3.1 was released.

Things I have tried:

- deactivating any plugins which might affect the checkout pages
- removing and reinstalling WooPayments

I wondered whether the authentication between WooPayments and Stripe needed to be renewed somehow, but I can't see how to do this.

EDIT

Managed to access the server logs, and found this:

```
{
  "installName": "vipreading",
  "environment": "PROD",
  "type": "error",
  "date": "2023-09-05T08:26:42.000Z",
  "severity": "notice",
  "client": "178.16.9.5:0",
  "message": "woocommerce_blocks_checkout_update_order_from_request is deprecated 
   since version 7.2.0!
   Use woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_from_request instead. 
   This action was deprecated in WooCommerce Blocks version 7.2.0. 
   Please use woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_from_request instead., 
   referer: https://www.vipreading.co.uk/checkout/",
  "uuid": "6dc7a682-19df-4142-a16a-18051f40006e"
}
```

That seems to imply I'm using an older version of WooCommerce Blocks, which has a bug that has since been fixed. However, looking at WooCommerce > Status, I'm apparently on WooCommerce Blocks 10.6.6.

I've tried to delete the checkout page so I can let WooCommerce recreate it, but it gets recreated identically as soon as I do so, and doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd hope there's more detail in the server logs if you can find them (web server error log, PHP-FPM error log if you have one, wp-content/debug.log if enabled)

Comment: But I agree: this sounds like Stripe configuration. I'd work through [the Stripe setup steps](https://woocommerce.com/document/stripe/) to make sure everything's correct, the API keys on your site match the API keys in your Stripe account etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it is WooPayments, which uses Stripe to handle the payments but doesn't seem to have the Account Settings section in the plugin settings, so I can't see how to reauthenticate the webhooks.

Comment: Ah, didn't appreciate the difference. It looks like that's a paid-for service so I'd talk to their support then.

Comment: Managed to get to the server logs, so have updated the original post with more info.

Comment: It could be the other way around: your WooCommerce blocks is too new for other things you've got, e.g. WooCommerce itself, other related plugins or your theme. Can you search all of your files for woocommerce_blocks_checkout_update_order_from_request ? Or possibly even the blocks on your payment page in the site editor somewhere. But please ask WooCommerce Payments for support with this too.

Comment: You could try winding back woocommerce-blocks to 7.1 in case that fixes this (please back up your site and database first). But also in general deprecation warnings don't break thinks, only warn of future problems, so this might not actually be it either.

Comment: You possibly don't need the woocommerce-blocks plugin at all: it's for bleeding edge WooCommerce block development and stable blocks are already bundled in WooCommerce itself.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try reverting to an older version of the blocks on the staging site. I'll also get in touch with WooPayments support and see if they can help.

You're right that I probably don't need the blocks plugin. I didn't have it initially, but added it when I saw that I was getting the deprecation issue to see if it solved anything.